# Call Command function every time Entry widget's value changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to call the `check_value` function every time the value entered in `Entry` widget changes, but it is only calling for the first time.

```
class table(tk.frame)
    ....
    ....#some functions
    def enterdata(self):
        ....
        ....
        for i in range(1,no_of_params):
            cell=work_sheet.cell(i,0)
            table.param_l.append(cell.value)
            var=StringVar()
            Button(middleframe,text=cell.value,width=40,height=2,command=lambda i=i :self.info(i)).grid(row=i+3,column=0)
            entry=Entry(middleframe,validate='focusout',validatecommand=lambda i=i:self.checkvalue(middleframe,i-1),\
                   textvariable=var,bd=5,width=30).grid(row=i+3,column=1)
            table.val.append(var)
            Label(middleframe,text="Enter value",width=15,height=2,bd=5).grid(row=i+3,column=2)

    def checkvalue(self,middleframe,r):
        if r==0:
            print table.val[r].get()    
            if "2" in table.val[r].get():
                        Label(middleframe,text="SUCCESS",fg="Dark Green",width=15,height=2,bd=5,\
                            font("Helvetica",11,"bold")).grid(row=r+4,column=2)
            else:
                        Label(middleframe,text="ERROR",fg="Dark Red",width=15,height=2,bd=5,\
                            font=("Helvetica",11,"bold")).grid(row=r+4,column=2)
        ......#similar checks for other values of 'r'
```

Comment: i want to call the check function everytime value in entry changes, but it is only calling for the first time

Comment: Is your code getting stuck in `checkvalue()`? Can you put a debug print or something at the end to make sure it returns?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: no it is not getting stuck in check value, i have checked this with a print statement. when i enter the value in other entry widget it calls the function if it is first time for that entry widget

Comment: @jonrsharpe from next time i will think before posting , this is my first time

Comment: Why *"from next time"*? You still can (and should) **edit this question**; providing a clearer example might help you actually get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function *must* return either `True` or `False`. If it does not, the validation is automatically turned off. Also, you cannot alter the value of the entry widget from within that procedure. You don't show your whole code so I don't know if that's what you're doing or not.

Also, you need to be careful when using both `validatecommand` and `textvariable` at the same time. As long as you only use `var` only for getting the value and never for setting it you should be ok.

From [the official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7) (upon which Tkinter is built):

> In general, the textVariable and validateCommand can be dangerous to
>   mix. Any problems have been overcome so that using the validateCommand
>   will not interfere with the traditional behavior of the entry widget.
>   Using the textVariable for read-only purposes will never cause
>   problems. The danger comes when you try set the textVariable to
>   something that the validateCommand would not accept, which causes
>   validate to become none (the invalidCommand will not be triggered).
>   The same happens when an error occurs evaluating the validateCommand.
>
> Primarily, an error will occur when the validateCommand or
>   invalidCommand encounters an error in its script while evaluating or
>   validateCommand does not return a valid Tcl boolean value. The
>   validate option will also set itself to none when you edit the entry
>   widget from within either the validateCommand or the invalidCommand.
>   Such editions will override the one that was being validated. If you
>   wish to edit the entry widget (for example set it to {}) during
>   validation and still have the validate option set, you should include
>   the command